# Python3.6 / OpenCV / Numpy / Amazon Lambda ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, numpy, opencv, aws-lambda

I am trying to import OpenCV and Numpy for my Lambda function on AWS.

I downloaded the libraries as preconised in another SO post from https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages

My .zip file has the following architecture

```
  .zip
    ├── cv2
    ├── numpy
    ├── lambda-function.py
    └── PIL
```

I have the following imports in my Python file:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import boto3

from PIL import Image
import uuid
import urllib.parse
```

I don't really get what I'm missing here, it works well with my local folder and I don't get the error when I run with Python2.7 on lambda (but I can't run the script because I need urllib).

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? That would help a lot to debug this

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?